# Commit to be stored only in a tag?

Tags: git

Here is the release process that I'd like to have:

- checkout branch master
- write new version number into file X
- commit
- tag
- push tag to `origin`

Is that possible to do this without pushing the branch?

I don't want my master branch (or any feature branch) filled with "version number increment" commits.

Comment: Not possible and not recommended AFAIK. Check out http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Comment: @rosipov I know git-flow, but what's the link with my question? I'd like to have the version number in a file.

Comment: You could create a throw-away branch, tag that, push the tag and remove the branch again. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Boldewyn solution would work. But I can't see the point of removing version upgrade commits from your history. These are part of a project's life, why remove them ?

Comment: @GuillaumeDarmont I would agree, but I don't want a release script to add v2.0.0 and leave it inside the v2.0 branch (which would lead to confusion, the v2.0 branch is **not** the v2.0.0)

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli Then why would you create tag `v2.0.0` in your local branch?

Comment: @JeanWaghetti I don't understand what you mean

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli If I understood correctly, your example says you have a local repo where, in branch `v2.0` you created a tag called `v2.0.0`. Then you want to push the tags but not the commits to the remote repo. Is it? If so, why would you need a tag that points nowhere?

Comment: That's for a "release" script. The script would checkout (for example) master, tag a release, and push the release (tag) back. I'd like to avoid 1) to clutter the history with "incrementing version number" commits 2) have the file containing the version number only in the tags, not on the branch, else you would be in `master` branch and the file would contain version number `v2.0.0`, which is confusing since a branch should not have a full version number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily do it of course by detaching head before committing and tagging:

```
git checkout --detach master
#write version number
git commit -am "version"
git tag newTag
git checkout master
```

But yes, it is weird thing to do as described in comments to your question. Additionally, instead creating the version file, maybe you could use `git describe` to produce a version name from tag names.

Comment: If I package my app in a zip, or simply there is no git installed, or the installed package is no longer a git repository, then `git describe` is useless :)